# Solve limit without use L'Hopital: $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{sin\left(2x\right)-2sin\left(x\right)}{x\cdot \:arctg^2x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Task:
$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin\left(2x\right)-2\sin\left(x\right)}{x\cdot \:arctan^2x}\right)$$

Hello! It is necessary to solve the next limit. I try several methods. For example, if you use the equivalent of small, it turns out:
$$\sin\left(2x\right)\rightarrow 2x$$
$$2\sin\left(x\right)\rightarrow 2x$$
$$x\cdot arc\tan^2\left(x\right)\rightarrow x\cdot x^2$$
Limit obtained indefinite again...(

I have tried to simplify the numerator (only in the numerator as the denominator have no idea what to do):
$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{2\sin x\cdot \cos x-2\sin x}{x\cdot arc\tan^2x}\right)=\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin x\left(\cos x-2\right)}{x\cdot arc\tan^2x}\right)=?$$

Comment: what is $arctg^2x$?

Comment: @VarunIyer I think it's another notation for $\arctan^2x$.

Comment: $\arctan ^2\left(x\right)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  *equivalents*:

Numerator: $\;\sin 2x-2\sin x=2\sin x(\cos x-1)$, and $\sin x\sim_0 x$, $\;\cos x-1\sim_0 -\dfrac{x^2}2$.

Denominator: $\;\arctan x\sim_0 x$.

Thus: $$\frac{\sin 2x-2\sin x}{x\arctan^2 x}\sim_0\frac{x(-x^2)}{x\cdot x^2}=-1.$$

Comment: So the answer must be $-1$

Comment: I beg you pardon? Did I miss something?

Comment: Well, you got $+\infty $. And it is necessary to limit equal $-1$.

Comment: Oops! I took a wrong version of the numerator. I'll correct that at once. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: ooooh, thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\dfrac{\sin2x-2\sin x}{x\arctan^2x}=-2\cdot\dfrac{\sin x}x\cdot\dfrac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\cdot\left(\dfrac x{\arctan x}\right)^2$$

and $$\dfrac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\dfrac1{(1+\cos x)}\cdot\left(\dfrac{\sin x}x\right)^2$$

Comment: And all this can now till the end simplify?

Comment: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac12$ is a basic limit.

Comment: @do.this,  You are aware of https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Sine_of_X_over_X?

Comment: @do.this, You miscalculated $$2\sin x\cos x-2\sin x=2\sin x(\cos x-1)$$

Comment: Had in mind, can you paint now all this together with a limit?

Comment: @do.this, Just put $$\lim_{x\to0}$$ in all the multiplicands in my answer

Answer (score 0):

So you have the following limit:

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin\left(2x\right)-2\sin\left(x\right)}{x\cdot \:\arctan^2x}\right)$$

I would suggest using taylor series:

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin\left(2x\right)-2\sin\left(x\right)}{x\cdot \:\arctan^2x}\right) = \frac{\left(2x - \frac{(2x)^3}{3!} + \frac{(2x)^5}{5!} - \ldots\right) - 2\left(x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \ldots\right)}{x\left(x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \ldots\right)^2} = \frac{-x^3 + \ldots}{x^3 + \ldots}$$

Note that we only care about the lowest power of $x$ on the numerator and the denominator. In this case it is $x^3$. Thus, if we multiply the fraction by $\frac{1}{x^3}$, we end up with:

$$\frac{-x^3 + \ldots}{x^3 + \ldots} = \frac{-1 + 0 + \ldots}{1 + 0 + \ldots} = -1$$

Therefore our answer is $-1$. Comment if you have questions.